# stringByReplacingOccurenceOfString fails

Tags: macos, nsstring, nsopenpanel

I'm trying to make a Mac OS X application that asks the user for a directory. I'm using an NSOpenPanel that gets triggered when the user presses a "Browse" button.

The problem is, [NSOpenPanel filenames] was deprecated, so now I'm using the URLs function. I want to parse out the stuff that's url related to just get a normal file path. So I tried `fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%%20" withString:@" "];`, but that gave me an error:

```
-[NSURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100521fa0
```

Here's the entire method:

```
- (void) browse:(id)sender
{
    int i; // Loop counter.

    // Create the File Open Dialog class.
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    // Display the dialog.  If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
    {
        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
        // files and directories selected.
        NSArray* files = [openDlg URLs];

        // Loop through all the files and process them.
        for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = (NSString*)[files objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"%@", fileName);

            // Do something with the filename.
            fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%%20" withString:@" "];

            NSLog(@"%@", fileName);
            NSLog(@"Foo");
            [oldJarLocation setStringValue:fileName];
            [self preparePopUpButton];
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, "Foo" never gets outputted to that console. It's like the method aborts at the stringByReplacigOccurencesOfString line.

If I remove that one line, the app will run and fill my text box with the string, just in URL form, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `NSArray` returned by `[NSOpenPanel URLs]` contains `NSURL` objects, not `NSString` objects. You're doing the following cast:

```
 NSString* fileName = (NSString*)[files objectAtIndex:i];
```

Since `NSArray` returns an `id`, there isn't any compile-time checking to make sure your cast makes sense, but you do get a runtime error when you try to send an `NSString` selector to what is actually an `NSURL`.

You *could* convert the `NSURL` objects to `NSString` and use your code mostly as-is, but there's no need for you to handle the URL decoding yourself. `NSURL` already has a method for retrieving the path portion which also undoes percent-encoding: [`path`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path).

```
NSString *filePath = [yourUrl path];
```

Even if your code *was* dealing with just a percent-encoded `NSString`, theres [`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'd still like to know why stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString didn't work though, as I feel like I'll need it in the future. If noone comes up with a better answer though, I'll mark the question as answered with your post.

Comment: If (NSString*) won't work for an NSURL, how would I convert between the two?

Comment: `NSString* urlString = [yourUrl absoluteString]`